# How to get rid of " java.net.UnknownHostException" error in java URL connection?

Tags: java, url

I want to close the URL connection after every instance of connection.

I have an url like - https://www.google.com/company_name"

The piece of code is

```
String URLfile = "https://www.google.com/company_name";// So to this URL I am 
//adding 100 Identities. 
//There are over 50000 identities and I am passing URLs 
//by appending identities with a batch size of 100. 

try{

// the length of the business Id is '100'
for(int i=0;i<businessId.length;i++){
            URLdata+=","+businessId[i];
        }
        System.out.println("the URL :"+URLdata);

        Step 1> Pass the URL
        URL url = new URL(URLdata);

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        // Step 2> to get the information from the website as an 'input stream'
        // Steps to get the data as an 'input stream' for the returned data 
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

        TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer xform = tfactory.newTransformer();

        // Step 3> Output the 'input  stream' onto an user defined 'XML' file
        // that's the default xform; use a stylesheet to get a real one
        // output the xml(input stream) information on to an XML file in the field specified in the program. 
        File myOutput = new File(XMLOutput);
        xform.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(myOutput));

        // Step 4> to parse the XML file to get the fields required for updating the database
        // Here we are parsing the XML file to get the information as specified
        // parsing the xml file for the information necessary 
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document docum = docBuilder.parse (new File(XMLOutput));

        // Step 4a) 
        // Read the XML file using the XPath for parsing the XML information
        // Creating an 'instance' of the XPath method
        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();


}

 catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println("There is an error :"+e);
 }
```

I am getting an `"java.net.UnknownHostException"`. Is it possible that I am closing the conneciton after every instance and so it is throwing the error? I am trying `conn.close()` but there is no function like that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `UnknownHostException` is pretty self-explanatory -- your JVM is unable to resolve the hostname you use

Comment: 1) From where is the `UnknownHostException` thrown?
2) What is the URL?  Does it resolve if you try to use it from a browser?

Comment: Check the stack trace likely the url.openConnection

Comment: @Pedantic Edited the question to include more details.

Comment: @fge How to solve the issue then, because I am using the same URL to get the information when I am entering it in the browser.

Comment: By any change, does your browser use a proxy?

Comment: @fge : Checked with "what is my Ip?" it shows no proxy detected. for your information I am using Ubutu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the for loop at the start is doing for you, but `UnknownHostException` is probably getting thrown by `URL url = new URL(URLdata);` because it doesn't know how to interpret whatever is in URLdata. Check and make sure the output of the `println` is always in a form that the constructor will like.

Comment: edited the question to include more details. As to the case of the URL construct , I am using the same URL construct in the browser and it returns information. thanks for asking. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused about the ambiguity of URLfile and URLdata in that case. Firstly, you're continuously appending a number to URLFile, so that by the end the string will look like `https://www.google.com/company_name12345678910...100`, but you aren't even using that string in this particular code anyway. So what is actually stored in the variable `URLdata`?

Comment: I have corrected it and changed URLfile to URLdata. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: No still not , the error happened when I was just posting the question on StackOverflow not in the program, it runs and gives the right output for a while but after that it throws the error.

Comment: I think you are really trying to replace `company_name` with the name stored in the businessID array, and in that case, you should also change your string construction to remove company name. Regardless, UnknownHostException is thrown when it can't resolve an IP address of a specified URL. If you're making random names that don't translate in the DNS, then this is going to get thrown when you try and create the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include this permission in your manifest file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score -1):

Resolved the issue by using

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
        .openConnection();
```

instead of

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
```

It solved the issue of timing out and too many connections as well.

thanks for all the suggestions and the references.

Comment: I get the same error using HttpURLConnection